# Bug in reputation update

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

I'm not clear why I have two different reputations. Also, sometimes, they sync "upwards" and sometimes "downwards". What gives?

[image]

Comment: The link you are using for the image returns a 404 error message.

Comment: Ah, copied wrong string, hihi.

Comment: Fixed the image. And standard answer: something something caching.

Comment: Hehe, I did the same change as you did and I was wondering - "what did the guy edited me for...", hihi. Now I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Bart How can it be caching when I reload the site? It would mean that reputations is loaded from two different variables...

Comment: Yes, I don't mean caching on your side, but caching on SO's side. From what I know, most such values are cached and do not always display the same values. But someone will certainly confirm or deny. So nothing more than a comment and guess from me. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reputation is just one; it is just that the one shown on the top of the page shows changes in real time, while the one shown in the screenshot comes from the cache.

The reputation on the top of the page is seen just from you, while the reputation on the profile page is seen from any user who visits your reputation page. I guess it doesn't have any sense to show real-time changes to other users, and this could take to not desired situations. I can imagine somebody saying "He lost 1 point exactly when I lost 2 points; it's him who down-voted me!"

Comment: +1 For the very good point about retribution. And it as **I** who assigned it to you! :)